# Android Emulator is not working in my lenovo g510

Tags: android, emulation

I m want to run android emulator in my laptop G510. when i run my application in android studio it says.
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
Please help me. How do I fix this error.!

Answer (score 0):

Check the CPU, it must be an Intel processor that supports VT and NX bit (XD) - you can check your CPU # at http://ark.intel.com 
Also make sure hyperV is off  *bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off* 
XD bit is on *bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn* 
Run the install again but use the installer from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager 
If you're using Avast, disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting. Restart the PC and try to run the HAXM installation again